# Interacting with one element in Android ListView affects multiple

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a list view of search items fetched from various web pages like so:

[image: Visual Aid]

There is a horizontal scroll view on the titles so that users can fully see the title. However, when I scroll on one of the items, another item about 6 down from the item I was interacting with is also scrolled to the right. How can I prevent this from happening?

Update: Here's my CustomAdapter Code:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements View.OnClickListener{

private ArrayList<Item> dataSet;
Context mContext;

// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView itemTitle;
    TextView itemStore;
    TextView itemPrice;
    ImageView storeLogo;
}

public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<Item> data, Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
    this.dataSet = data;
    this.mContext=context;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int position=(Integer) v.getTag();
    Object object= getItem(position);
    Item item=(Item)object;

    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.store:
            Snackbar.make(v, "This item is being sold at " + item.getStore() + "." , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("No action", null).show();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Item item = getItem(position);

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

    final View result;

    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        //viewHolder.itemStore = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        viewHolder.itemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        viewHolder.storeLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.store);

        result = convertView;

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result = convertView;
    }

    viewHolder.itemTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    viewHolder.itemPrice.setText("$" + item.getPrice());
    viewHolder.storeLogo.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewHolder.storeLogo.setTag(position);

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;

}
```

}

Here is my fragment_search.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.painlessshopping.mohamed.findit.Search$PlaceholderFragment">



<Button
    android:text="Next Page"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonUp"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="49dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Previous Page"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonDown"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonUp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:hint="What can I help you find?"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id ="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_height="375dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText" />
```

Here is my row_item.xml (For the custom adapter)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Sample Text for Android Horizontal Scroll View Goes Here"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/dgrey"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/store"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:text="$39.99"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It'd be useful to at least see your Adapter code, or however you handle the scrolling part that affects the others

Comment: I added the adapter code and the two relevant layout resource xmls, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Is it always the same distance apart that the views are affected?

Comment: i think in this case you have to ignore checking "convertView == null" and always generate new view.

Comment: Yes it is. There are always exactly 5 elements in between

Comment: Thanks @pooyan , that worked. But I'm just curious, what else will that affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of performance in constructor we check and see if we are able , we will use the previous layout that has generated, and just try to replace their values, but in your case because you can not change the scrol bar of view so your new item and previous items will have the same scroll bar view. i hope i were clear. so you have to always generate new layout like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// Get the data item for this position
Item item = getItem(position);

// Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

final View result;


    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
    viewHolder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    //viewHolder.itemStore = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
    viewHolder.itemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    viewHolder.storeLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.store);

    result = convertView;

    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

viewHolder.itemTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
viewHolder.itemPrice.setText("$" + item.getPrice());
viewHolder.storeLogo.setOnClickListener(this);
viewHolder.storeLogo.setTag(position);

// Return the completed view to render on screen
return convertView;

}
```

also maybe there were a better way that i don't know, but this will solve your problem at least.

**UPDATE** :
for more information about how listview work and performance tip [this link](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) seem's good